# SyntaxError during rebuilding react-map-gl-draw

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, build, babeljs

I was trying to modify the source code of react-map-gl-draw, but error occurs when I run npm run build
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb7u2.png)

`$ rm -fr dist-es6 && BABEL_ENV=es6 babel src --config-file  ../../babel.config.js --out-dir dist-es6 --source-maps inline --  extensions .ts,.tsx SyntaxError: src/constants.ts: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7) > 1 | export enum GEOJSON_TYPE { |        ^ 2 |   POINT = 'Point', 3 |   LINE_STRING = 'LineString', 4 |   POLYGON = 'Polygon', error Command failed with exit code 1.`

I think it might be a babel thing or whatever else ,eagering for your guys help!!!!!!!!！